# Databases vs Files (performance)

Tags: c++, database, performance, file, filesystems

My C++ program has to **read** information about 256 images **just one time**. The information is simple: the path and some floats per image.

I don't need any kind of concurrent access. Also, I don't care about writing, deleting or updating the information and I don't have to do any kind of complex query. This is my pipeline:

1. Read information about one image.
2. Store that information on a object.
3. Do some calculation with the information.
4. Delete the object.
5. Next image.

I can use 256 files (every image has the same information), 1 file with all the information or a PostgreSQL databases. **What will be faster?**

Comment: i believe files is simpler and faster option in your case looking at the magnitude of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Your question 'which will be faster' is tricky as performance is dependent on so many different factors, including OS, whether the database or file system are on the same machines as your application, the size of the images etc. I would guess that you could find some combinations that would make any of your options faster if you try hard enough.

Having said that, if everything is running on the same machine, then a file based approach would seem intuitively to be faster than a database, just because a database generally provides more functionality, and hence does more work (not just serving requests but in the background also) so has to use more of your computing power.

Similarly, it seems intuitive that a single file will be more efficient than multiple files as it saves the opening (and closing if necessary) operations associated with multiple files. But, again, giving an absolute answer is hard as opening and closing multiple files may be a common use case that certain OS's have optimised, hence making it as fast (or even faster) than a just using a single file.

If performance is very important for your solution, it is hard to avoid having to do some comparative testing with your target deployment systems.